# Error accessing files in jenkins postbuild action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, post-build-event

summary
reports are located here:\pc1\tests\Env\Getreport.html \pc1\tests\Env\Getreport.xml
file:////Users/jenkins/Documents/Reports

```
Sending email to: build@mydomain.com
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
ERROR: Error accessing files to attach: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'C:/Users/jenkins/Documents/Reports/'. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

this got figured getting

```
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
Sending email to: users@mydomain.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

but did not get email from Editable Email notification, but yes email works with postbuild email notification

Answer (score 0):

Working fine by updating the correct directory path